# What is the right way to override default event handler behaviors (e.g. toggle trace visibility on click)?

Tags: plotly

I'd like to be able to opt-out of [the default `plotly_legendclick` behavior](https://github.com/plotly/plotly.js/blob/13eb982ec9700ee9fe6cb8a93ee12d4ee8b0a215/src/components/legend/handle_click.js#L95-L190) (as well as for other events). I can't seem to find this in the docs, but it seems that returning a falsey value from a plotly event handler does what I want (see this [codepen](https://codepen.io/jacobq_/pen/LrBMBO?editors=0010)). Is that the right way? No `preventDefault` or `stopPropagation`?

**Clarification:** Ideally, I would like an authoritative answer that cites documentation or comes from a Plotly.js collaborator (rather than a conjecture based on the current behavior of the source code).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Plotly team member [Alex C Johnson answers the question here](https://community.plot.ly/t/disable-legend-click-functionality-hiding-traces/1345/4).

> As of v1.37 (and specifically https://github.com/plotly/plotly.js/pull/2581) you can disable hiding traces by legend click using the plotly_legendclick event:
>   `gd.on('plotly_legendclick',function() { return false; })`

Answer (score 1):

Lets look at the actual code shall we. Below is the snippet, it is located from line `108238` from the [plotly.js](https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-latest.js) script file.

```js
var clickVal = Events.triggerHandler(gd, 'plotly_legendclick', evtData);
if(clickVal === false) return;

if(numClicks === 1) {
    legend._clickTimeout = setTimeout(function() {
        handleClick(legendItem, gd, numClicks);
    }, DBLCLICKDELAY);
}
else if(numClicks === 2) {
    if(legend._clickTimeout) clearTimeout(legend._clickTimeout);
    gd._legendMouseDownTime = 0;

    var dblClickVal = Events.triggerHandler(gd, 'plotly_legenddoubleclick', evtData);
    if(dblClickVal !== false) handleClick(legendItem, gd, numClicks);
}
```

Here we see that they have defined the event `plotly_legendclick` and the return value is stored in a variable(`clickVal`).

So the next immediate line is.

```js
if(clickVal === false) return;

if(numClicks === 1) {
    legend._clickTimeout = setTimeout(function() {
        handleClick(legendItem, gd, numClicks);
    }, DBLCLICKDELAY);
}
```

So we can see that there is no need for `preventDefault` or `stopPropagation`, since we never enter the code that handles the event (`handleClick`) when the value returned on click is `false`!!

Comment: I realize that returning false prevents the default behavior, but I would like to know whether or not this is how the library was intended to be used. In other words, is this public/stable API? It seems odd to me that this convention would be used alone because although there is a [similar one](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/webappapis.html#the-event-handler-processing-algorithm) in normal DOM event handling, there are also more granular capabilities like [`preventDefault`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault) in that case that won't stop propagation.

Comment: Also, [here](https://github.com/plotly/plotly.js/blob/ef6b259f09c54774721e9ecfea808f84561d5f69/src/components/legend/draw.js#L382) is a link to the actual source, not the dist package.

Comment: @iX3 Both the codes represent the the same thing I guess, anyway, just use `return false`, I dont think you will find any noticeable change in behaviour

Comment: That is only true for this specific version. If it's not part of the public API then it might change any time (breaking anything that depends on it). That's why I am seeking a reference that shows whether or not I can rely on it.

Comment: @iX3 Apart from this raise it in plotly github page and also in plotly forums!

Comment: Thanks for suggesting the Plotly community forum. I was able to find the answer there (see accepted answer).

Comment: @iX3   Good Job! :)